# Read out columnwidth to adjust in TikzEdit/ Global Node Points

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm just trying to get all my Matlab Figures in TikZ and it works well. But in some figures I need to do changes. So I downloaded TikzEdt which I think is a good WYSIWYG-Tool.

Now I'm setting my axes to coordinates (0,0) and I define the size of my plots all over my document with `{0.4\columnwidth}` and `{0.75\columnwidth}` for `height` and `width`.

I am also defining these in my example .tex file which I import to TikzEdt. But my problem now is, that the preview or coordinates in TikzEdt preview don't match my actual document.

How can I read out the exact value of `\columnwidth` from my LaTeX document, or how can I set global coordinates/nodes in TikzEdt, so that they will match the final document.

I'm thankful for every advice.

Comment: `\typeout{col width is \the\columnwidth}` will put the width in the log, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that helped me. I had to read out the columnwidth and set it in my TikZeDT, so that the node points fit! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
\typeout{col width is \the\columnwidth}
```

will put the width in the log.